# Annotations JAVA Validar un dato que solo debe contener letras y espacios

Tags: regex

Tengo que validar los string firstName y lastName para que solo acepte letras y espacios. Como seria la Regular expression usando Pattern?
Ademas, el string email no debe existir en la base de datos anteriormente, es decir no debe repetirse.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserRequest {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @Email(message = "This email has invalid format")
  private String email;

  @Length(max = 8, min = 6, message = "The password must be between 6 and 8 characters")
  private String password;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

tienes muchas preguntas en una, pero te respondere algo breve para cada caso ya que todo se relaciona con el api de validaciones de java (o casi todo).

para ponerle una expresion regular personalizada en la validacion usa

```
@Pattern(regexp=".+", message="tu nombre no es normal")
```

y para el caso del email, en tu capa de persistencia si es que usas hibernate usa

```
@Column(unique=true)
```